# Composer Use Local Git Bundle As it Would a Git Repo

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

I have a scenario in which the machine I'm deploying to doesn't have direct access to the Git repo. So the solution is that I have a Git bundle of my repo copied locally to the machine where the code will deploy.

So it looks like this.

`/var/local/repos/MyGitRepo/MyGitRepo.git`

If I want to use this with the normal git client, I could do

`git clone /var/local/repos/MyGitRepo/MyGitRepo.git MyGitRepo`

And I have a checkout of the MyGitRepo in the MyGitRepo directory.

My question is, when I use composer to install the MyGitRepo, I have to refer to the MyGitRepo checked out Git repo, rather than the `/var/local/repos/MyGitRepo/MyGitRepo.git`

So the repositories looks like this:

```
{
 "type" : "vcs",
  "url" : "/where/i/put/MyGitRepo"
}
```

This works, but can't I just point composer to the git repo rather than the checked out git repo?

I feel like this should work:

```
{
 "type" : "vcs",
  "url" : "/var/local/repos/MyGitRepo/MyGitRepo.git"
}
```

I get this problem reported.

> The requested package mygitrepo could not be found in any version,
>   there may be a typo in the package name.

If I have to point composer to a checked out local repo, that's fine, but it seems like I should be able to use that .git bundle as I would any Git repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`path`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) type of repo to create a symlink in your vendor folder that will point to your clone. Taken from the docs:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/var/local/repos/MyGitRepo/MyGitRepo.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/package": "*"
    }
}
```

Comment: I already can point to the clone, I want to not have to make a clone.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. What's the difference between "git repo" and "checked out git repo"? The `path` repository can point to any directory on the disk that has your package. It doesn't have to be a git clone.

Comment: That's part of the problem, I don't know what things are called. I want to point to the .git file in my composer like we do when referencing a git repo via ssh or whatever. I don't normally point composer at a cloned checkout of a git repo.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You need to have a package somewhere on your disk (either git checkout or uploaded to your server) and then you can use `path` repository type in your `composer.json` to point to it.

Comment: I think you're right, I just wanted to verify that I'm not missing something with git. It just seems like it should work to point to this /var/local/repos/cphython.git versus git@github.com:python/cpython.git

Comment: Your answer is correct, I just can't do what I want to with git.